# find past versions of app script in new editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, revision-history

I accidently overwrote a long function. I want to revert to an older, working version of my code.gs file.

App script auto saves every time I debugged the script.

I assume the older saved versions are found in Executions but when I open the project or container I'm presented with the current version of my script. ??

How do I get, view, or load a past iteration of my scripts?

thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but one option might be to use the App Script API to rollback your project deployment to an earlier version. The new IDE does not have full feature parity with the old editor, so be sure to send feedback to Google so that they are aware of what's lacking.

Comment: When you say `App script auto saves every time I debugged the script`, do you mean you are creating a new [version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions) for deployment? If you only mean the project is getting saved, like via clicking the disk symbol (`Save project`), then I don't think you can retrieve and earlier "version". Apps Script files don't have [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions), unlike Sheets or Docs.

Answer (score 5):

Only the current file revision is available to view in the new editor.  Previous file revisions must be accessed using the legacy editor.  To view previous file revisions:

1. Click "Use legacy editor".
2. **(Optional)** Select Missing file version history in the Editor Opt-out Survey, click Submit, then close the survey window.
3. Click on the tab of the file that you want to see the history of.
4. Select File > See version history or use Ctrl+Alt+Shift+H.

You can now view the revision history of the file and restore a previous version of the file if needed. When you're done,  click "Use new editor" to go back to the new editor if desired.